# AngularJS databinding with 2 different GET functions

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

My problem is as follows:
this is my html code for how I show my dropdown menu:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-click="getExercise()">Semester 1<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a href="#Opdracht" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" ng-repeat="item in ex | orderBy: 'week'" ng-click="getExercise(item.week)">week {{item.week}}</a>
                        <!--<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#Opdracht" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-click="getExercise(1)">Labo 1</a></li>
                        </ul>-->
                    </li>
```

Notice how I use `getExercise()` to get all the exercises in the NoSQL database and then I create a `<a>` tag for each exercise with their responsive value for property "week" as their content.

Also notice that this has an `href=#Opdracht` so basically clicking on this opens the panel called Opdracht. ALSO, and here is where my problem starts, As you click on the chosen week in the dropdown menu, I call the getExercise() method again but this time I give a parameter which is the value for the "week" property. This will search my NoSQL database for a document with a value for "week" equal to the parameter value. for example: If I click on "week 1" I will call upon getExercise(1) with parameter 1 to parse for a document with "week = 1". 
The code for the #Opdracht panel is posted underneath:

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="Opdracht" class="collapse">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading text-center">{{ex.title}}</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="(key, val) in ex" ng-hide="$index<3">{{key}}: {{val}}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Totale score: {{ex.score + ex.extra_score}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <a href="#Opdracht" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse">Close</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the main problem:
As I click on "week 1" I get the panel with the correct information correctly shown. BUT when I click on "semester 1" in the nav-bar. I will call upon `getExercise()` to parse all documents again to fill in the dropdown menu. But at the same time, All records will be shown inside the `#Opdracht` panel because I parse for All records, therefore the scope will be reset.
How can I fix this so that the shown content for #Opdracht panel remains the same even after I click semester one again?

Comment: Could you set up a basic Plunk?

Comment: @JordanMcRae  http://plnkr.co/edit/DI442H5BvFsIwHT1d9AR?p=preview does this help?